# Alternative to "While > 127 subtract 128"

Tags: variables, lua

I'm writing an algorithm that generates 4 values between 0 and 127, based on an input number. It looks like this:

```
value = {}
input = number
mod = input * 2 - 1
value[1] = input - 1
value[2] = input - 1 + mod
value[3] = input - 1 + mod*2
value[4] = input - 1 + mod*3
```

To make sure the resulting numbers remain between 0 and 127 for larger numbers, I have this in place:

```
for i = 1, 4 do
while value[i] > 127 do
value[i] = value[i] - 128
end
end
```

This works as intended, but as the generated numbers grow larger, this method becomes extremely slow. For instance, if the input number is 400000, value[4] will become 2799996. Reducing that to a number below 127 using my method takes quite a while. Is there a better way to do  this?
Any and all suggestions will be much appreciated!

Comment: Why not just use modulo?

Comment: I am not sure what modulo is, or how to use it. I'll take a look at the LUA manual. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Modulo solved my problem. I had no idea it was a thing; I better retake maths.
The while loop is out the window, new code looks like this:

```
for i = 1, 4 do
value[i] = value[i] % 128
end
```

It was that simple, thank you Sami Kuhmonen!